# drivers for HP XW6200

Tags: drivers, downloads

i am using computer from 10 years,  now i am going try UBUNTU 13.04.  I have HP WORKSTATION XW6200, please help me to download drivers for this pc for UBUNTU 13.04.  It will be my first try to install ubuntu,  but i want to download drivers first.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 13.04 on that system, would probably work, with the hardware that you have.  You may want to pay attention to Graphics, since the machine come with different options for graphics.  If it comes with the NVIDIA Quadro4 400 NVS, you may have a problem.

Personally, I would recommend that you boot from the Ubuntu CD, and Try it before installing.

Below are links were you can find the driver for the other graphics card the system my come with.

[Nvidia quadro nvs 280](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux_display_ia32_185.18.36)

[Nvidia quadro fx 330](http://www.nodevice.com/driver/Quadro_FX_330/get37269.html)

[ATI Firegl v3100](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx)

[NVIDIA Quadro FX 1300](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux_display_amd64_173.14.25.html)

For Network Adapters:

[Intel Pro 1000 MT](http://www.intel.com/support/network/sb/cs-006120.htm)

[Broadcom Netxtreme Bcm5782](http://server206-173.live-servers.net/broadcom/broadcomboot/broadcom.asp?keywords=broadcom%20netxtreme%20bcm5782%20gigabit%20ethernet%20linux%20driver&recor=1)

[Broadcom 5751 Gigabit Ethernet](http://www.broadcom.com/support/ethernet_nic/downloaddrivers.php)