# Issue on installing Ubuntu HP xw9300

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, graphics

I'm quite new to ubuntu. I installed it sucessfully on a Laptop, and a regular PC. 
I am now trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on a hp xw9300 Workstation.

Hardware specification can be found [here](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay&spf_p.prp_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-navigationalState=docId%253Demr_na-c00293051-2%257CdocLoc%28ale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken#N1000E)

I have NVIDIA Quadro NVS 280 Graphics Card.

The installer from an usb key run smoothly.

But when I boot the PC right after, I can t have a graphical display.(I just have the desktop background of Ubuntu; no tool bars).  The console mode works fine.

I have the same problem with both i86 and amd64 versions of ubuntu.

The error I have:

```
[TTM] failed to find memory space for buffer eviction
E[Xorg[1106]] fail ttm_validate
E[Xorg[1106]] validate vram_list
E[Xorg[1106]] validate: -12
```

And this is repeating.

I manage to run apt-get update, apt-get upgrade from console. 
I browsed the web to find answers.
If you have any idea of what could be blocking, any help will be welcome.

Reguards.

Comment: Here is a link to similar to your question:http://askubuntu.com/questions/312150/drivers-for-hp-xw6200

Comment: Yep I downloaded this driver, but how do I install it from the console ? The pc won't mount an usb key.
(Assuming drive cache: write through / Asking for cache data failed); gonna try to figure out how to get the driver.

Comment: trying wget at www.us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/185.18.36/NVIDIA-Linux-x86-185.18.36-pkg1.run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost solved the problem with http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2081649

I had a driver issue. Quadro FX 330 GPU with Quadro NVS 280 GPU PCI.

Correct driver is 173.14xx currently    173.1439 .

I will try your solution if I can't make it work fully (got low resolution until now !)
You posted as I was posting.

And edit, I have indeed 12.04.4. In amd64 version.

Answer (score 0):

In those case, you would try following two methods:

**1. Try install the fourth point update to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.**

*If you are in use of this, skip to **2.***

Ubuntu 12.04.4  features a new version of the Ubuntu kernel, version 3.11, and matching X.org stack, aimed at providing existing LTS users with improved support for ‘a wider variety of hardware’ including your computer.

Here is a link to download Ubuntu 12.04.4:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

**2. Try to use HWE(Hardware Enablement)**

First of all, run `cat /etc/lsb-release` to confirm your Ubuntu version.
It shows you Ubuntu version exactly.
After that, open console, please run following command:

- Precise 12.04.2:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-quantal xserver-xorg-lts-quantal libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal
  ```
- Precise 12.04.3:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-raring xserver-xorg-lts-raring libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-raring
  ```
- Precise 12.04.4:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-saucy xserver-xorg-lts-saucy libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-saucy
  ```

I'm also experienced solving this problem as the same you have.

Comment: following the tuto I mentioned in my response, they were already installed.
My issue is, the 173.14xx drivers recommanded by nvidia and ubuntu don't work. Or i need to remove the previous one manually to install them. with "nvidia-current-updates" I have a fonctionnal GUI.